# Redirecting breaks output (Python Script)

Tags: python, io-redirection, nohup

I am running the same **python script** multiple times **redirecting the output** in different ways and getting **broken output**. Sometimes **lines are missing** and sometimes the **order is reversed**. The python script includes a number of print statements which I would like to print to an output file.

First of all let me show you how the output should look like:

```
Number of haplotypes: 400000,400000,400000
Number of trees: 2946715
Number of mutations: 3454912
Sequence length: 62949445.0
True PRS read from file: ../data/prs_true/prs.prs_true. 600000 lines imported.
Defining cases/controls [2020-07-27 23:26:09]
Case control variables saved to ../data/case_control/c_c.case_control.pickle.
End
```

**Run A:** I am running the script with default output: my screen. The order of print statements is correct, but the last two print statements are missing:

```
(genPy2) [user@vm code]$ python simulate_prs_py2.py --tree ../data/tree/tree.hdf5 --true_prs ../data/prs_true/prs.prs_true --ncausal=200 --h2=0.33 --out ../data/case_control/sim_full
Number of haplotypes: 400000,400000,400000
Number of trees: 2946715
Number of mutations: 3454912
Sequence length: 62949445.0
True PRS read from file: ../data/prs_true/prs.prs_true. 600000 lines imported.
Defining cases/controls [2020-07-27 23:24:48]
```

**Run B:** Now I am running the same script and redirecting the output to a file "output.txt". Now it prints the first few lines to my screen and the last two lines to the file. Why not everything to the file? Further the order is mixed up now: The first line of the file (True PRS...) should come before the last line of the screen output (Defining cases...).

```
(genPy2) [user@vm code]$ python simulate_prs_py2.py --tree ../data/tree/tree.hdf5 --true_prs ../data/prs_true/prs.prs_true --ncausal=200 --h2=0.33 --out ../data/case_control/sim_full > output.txt
Number of haplotypes: 400000,400000,400000
Number of trees: 2946715
Number of mutations: 3454912
Sequence length: 62949445.0
Defining cases/controls [2020-07-27 23:25:22]
```

```
(genPy2) [user@vm code]$ cat output.txt 
True PRS read from file: ../data/prs_true/prs.prs_true. 600000 lines imported.
Case control variables saved to ../data/case_control/c_c.case_control.pickle.
End
```

**Run C:** I am now using nohup and saving the output to a file "../data/case_control/output.txt". Now all the output is redirected to the output file but the order of the two statements "True PRS..." and "Defining cases..." is still reversed.

```
(genPy2) [user@vm code]$ nohup python simulate_prs_py2.py --tree ../data/tree/tree.hdf5 --true_prs ../data/prs_true/prs.prs_true --ncausal=200 --h2=0.33 --out ../data/case_control/sim_full > ../data/case_control/output.txt
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
```

```
(genPy2) [user@vm code]$ cat ../data/case_control/output.txt 
Number of haplotypes: 400000,400000,400000
Number of trees: 2946715
Number of mutations: 3454912
Sequence length: 62949445.0
Defining cases/controls [2020-07-27 23:26:09]
True PRS read from file: ../data/prs_true/prs.prs_true. 600000 lines imported.
Case control variables saved to ../data/case_control/c_c.case_control.pickle.
End
```

I am 80% certain, that this is a problem in the shell and not in my python script. Everything is fine, should that be the case. However, it is crucial that the python script runs properly.

Any suggestions why this occurs and how to fix it are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your script is printing some things to `stdout` (`output.txt` in case B) and some to `stderr` (the rest).

Comment: @Panki found it. Thank you. I didn't know that was a thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recycled a python script without knowing one detail:

The script runs in Python 2 and imports a `print` function from the `__future___` package as `eprint`. This got printed to `stderr` while everything printed with `print` (the Python 2 default) got printed to `stdout`. This caused

- the `print` statements missing in Run A and the `eprint` statements to show on screen
- the `print` statements to be saved to "output.txt" in Run B while the `eprint` statements were saved
- nohub directs both `stderr` as well as `stdout` into the file. So in Run C, everything got directed to the output file. However, I still can't explain the reversed order.

Only using `eprint` solved all my problems.

Thanks to @Panki for directing me here